# cakephp, linux & mssql

Tags: sql-server, linux, cakephp, pdo

This question has been asked here a number of times, but I have never found a correct solution.

Basically cake 2.x moved to PDO, effectively dropping support for MSSQL on Linux.

Our existing implementation using FreeTDS and CakePHP 1.3.14 worked fine.  Now that I've almost completed the upgrade to 2.4.2 the Mssql support for Linux is a big pain.

The code we have actually connects to both MySQL and MSSQL databases.

My options are:
1) Move to a Windows server, which I don't want to do.
2) Port over the Odbc.php from cake 1.3 into cake 2.4.2 and use that instead
3) Try and hack up Sqlsrv.php (or extend it) and use dblib (sybase) to connect
4) Use the Datasource plugin (branch mssql-2.0).  Kind of works, it extends DboSource.php but doesn't implement a number of things properly.

So, not sure where to go from here. Would love to get a hacked PDO solution working.

Anyone in this situation got a resolution?

Comment: "Basically cake 2.x moved to PDO, effectively dropping support for Linux." WHAT?

Comment: Dropping support for MSSQL linux.

Answer (score 0):

Searching for the same problem, I came across a post in Nabble that has links to a  [**Linux native ODBC driver for MSSQL**](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=28160) recently released by Microsoft.

This may come in handy: http://cakephp.1045679.n5.nabble.com/SQL-Server-Linux-and-CakePHP-2-tp5463357p5464129.html